# PDFKit is vertically flipping PDFPage initialised with image

Tags: ios, pdf, uiimage

Not sure if this is a bug as PDFKit is in Beta on iOS, but when I create a PDFDocument based on an array of images (using PDFPage(image:), it flips the image vertically.

```
@IBAction func export(_ sender: Any){
    let apdf = PDFDocument()
    var i = 0
    while i < arrayOfImages.count{
        let image = arrayOfImages[i]
        let pdfpage = PDFPage(image: image)
        apdf.insert(pdfpage!, at: i)
        i = i + 1
    }
    //Code for sharing the PDF Document
    let objectsToShare = [apdf.dataRepresentation()]
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

    activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
    self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The output is this:

[image]

When it should be this: [image]

I am 100% sure that the source images are not flipped because they are used elsewhere in the app. You can set the rotation of a PDFPage but I can't see any way to manually flip it back.

Answer (score 1):

One (bad) solution to this bug (?) is to flip the image vertically in advance so it gets flipped back:

```
let img = arrayOfImages[i]
let image = UIImage(cgImage: img.cgImage!, scale: img.scale, orientation: .downMirrored)
let pdfpage = PDFPage(image: image)
```

Comment: Indeed, this is strange. I hope we'll don't get into troubles once they fix the bug... but thanks a lot for the workaround! Got me going again.

Comment: @Holtwick are you still using that fix? I have the same weird issue.

Comment: @George indeed, I checked it again and the bug seems to be gone in the latest iOS release. It now works without flipping.

Comment: @Holtwick thanks, I need to ensure I'm on the very last version :)