# Pictures taken with the camera in my app are upside down

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, uiimage

When I use the camera to take a picture in my app the images are then displayed upside down.

I use a UIImagePickerController to take a photo and just select the one i am happy with.  Upon selection, the following function is execute:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    print("image selected ...")
    // Get picked image info dictionary
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    // Image is upside down. Need to re-orient


    // Add captured and selected image to your Photo Library
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)

    // Create PDFDocument object and display in PDFView
    let document = createPDFDataFromImage(image: image)

    myPDFView.document = document

    // Dimiss imagePicker
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}


func createPDFDataFromImage(image: UIImage) -> PDFDocument{
    let document = PDFDocument.init()
    let imagePDF = PDFPage.init(image: image)

    document.insert(imagePDF!, at: 0)
    return document
}
```

How can I stop the pictures from being upside down?

Comment: Do you need to actually flip the imag? Do you want a new image that you can save that is the flipped version? Or do you jut want to display it upside down?

Comment: I just need to flip it upside down for viewing - before saving

Comment: So you do want to save an upside down version of it?

Comment: whats happening is when i take the photo and it is displayed, its upside down for some reason, so i need to flip it 180 deg

Comment: surely it would be better to work out why your photos are upside down in the first place and stop that from happening. Look up XY Problem. This is a perfect example. Can you show the code you are using to take the photos. http://xyproblem.info

Comment: I fixed your question for you. Just add the code for how you are taking and displaying the photos and I’ll take a look.

Comment: @Fogmeister please see updated question

Comment: Can you show your `createPDFDataFromImage` function

Comment: @Fogmeister please see update

Comment: Is the image that is saved to the Photos album also upside down? Or is that one the right way round and only the PDF is upside down?

Comment: @Fogmeister just the pdf. in the photo album it is in the correct orientation

Comment: It is very likely that the image is not upside down when you get it, but is just shown upside down when you display it. This can happen when you show the image in a CALayer instead of a UIImage, for example, due to the flipped coordinate system of CALayer.

Comment: Closed as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46219729/pdfkit-is-vertically-flipping-pdfpage-initialised-with-image also... this looks like a bug. Might be an idea to raise a radar for this. You can do that at http://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
    var flippedImage: UIImage?

    if let origImage = UIImage(named: "s1") {
        if let cg = origImage.cgImage {
            flippedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cg, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.downMirrored)
        }
    }

    theImageView.image = flippedImage
```